# executeDispatch synchronous?

Tags: java, openoffice.org, japplet, uno

I'm working on a java Applet which has a document loaded. On this Applet I have a custom "print" button which basically inits the print process of the document. This is the code that is executed after this button is pressed:

```
PropertyValue[] printProperties = new PropertyValue[1];
printProperties[0] = new PropertyValue();
printProperties[0].Name = "Print";
printProperties[0].Value = new Boolean(true);

xDispatchProvider = (XDispatchProvider)UnoRuntime.queryInterface (XDispatchProvider.class, xFrame);
dispatcher.executeDispatch(xDispatchProvider, ".uno:Print","_self", 0, printProperties);

someOtherProcess();
```

This code opens the native(?) print dialog which is the expected behaviour, and works so far. The problem is the "someOtherProcess" method. I need to execute this method right after the print dialog is closed either by pressing its "print" button or canceling/closing the print dialog.

Since executeDispatch is async I tried to make it synchronous using the "SynchronMode" in the PropertyValue[] with no success.

I found a way to listen to print events which are fired when the print process starts or when it's cancelled. This is the whole code:

```
PropertyValue[] printProperties = new PropertyValue[1];
printProperties[0] = new PropertyValue();
printProperties[0].Name = "Print";
printProperties[0].Value = new Boolean(true);

xDispatchProvider = (XDispatchProvider)UnoRuntime.queryInterface (XDispatchProvider.class, xFrame);

dispatcher.executeDispatch(xDispatchProvider, ".uno:Print","_self", 0, printProperties);

XPrintJobBroadcaster xPrintJobBroadcaster = (XPrintJobBroadcaster)UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPrintJobBroadcaster.class, xComponent);  
xPrintJobBroadcaster.addPrintJobListener(new MyPrintJobListener());



class MyPrintJobListener implements XPrintJobListener {
    public void printJobEvent(PrintJobEvent printJobEvent) {
        AppletLogger.log("printing");
    }
    public void disposing(com.sun.star.lang.EventObject eventObject) {
        AppletLogger.log("disposing");
    }
}
```

The "printJobEvent" is fired when the print process has either started, finished, cancelled and so on, but I can't find a way to know if the print dialog has been cancelled or closed as this doesn't fire any print event.

So my main questions are, is there a way to open a print dialog in a synchronous way so that the programs waits for the print dialog to close?
Is there a way to listen to the close event of the native print dialog window?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I'm working on a java Applet.."* You're a couple of years too late. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: Thanks for the info @AndrewThompson, I already knew that. The thing is at my company we are still working with these applets for the customers that don't want an upgrade.

Comment: *"..for the customers that don't want an upgrade"* There comes a time when a company has to decide whether it will cost more to cater to customers wallowing in their obsolescence, or dump them. It is now such that it will cost more to cater to them.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [State](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/view/PrintJobEvent.html#State) property.  If printing is cancelled, it should first show `JOB_STARTED` (which is 0) and then `JOB_ABORTED` (which is 3).

```
class MyPrintJobListener implements XPrintJobListener {
    public void printJobEvent(PrintJobEvent printJobEvent) {
        AppletLogger.log("print status: " + printJobEvent.State.getValue());
    }
    public void disposing(com.sun.star.lang.EventObject eventObject) {
        AppletLogger.log("disposing");
    }
}
```

Also the dispatcher didn't work for me.  Use the API interface instead:

```
XPrintJobBroadcaster xPrintJobBroadcaster = (XPrintJobBroadcaster)
    UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPrintJobBroadcaster.class, xComponent);  
xPrintJobBroadcaster.addPrintJobListener(new MyPrintJobListener());

XPrintable xPrintable =
    (XPrintable)UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPrintable.class, xComponent);
xPrintable.print(printProperties);

try { Thread.sleep(10000); } catch (Exception e) {}  // Wait for print job.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jim, I already knew that I can check the state of the print process. If you press the "print" button the print process is started and either the success or the fail of the process will be notified printJobEvent method. Also the second solution doesn't open the print dialog and I need it.